# TGauge doesn't change value in runtime

Tags: delphi-7, gauge, delphi-10.2-tokyo

At first, please bear with me, as I am quite new to the Delphi world.  I am a former C++, C# and embedded developer.

I have Delphi 7 and Delphi RAD Studio 10.2 Starter on Windows 7 64-bit.

I have tried the `TGauge` component in both versions, as it is standard in Delphi (I think).

So, the issue is when I try to set the `Progress` property with a value at run-time, it doesn't reflect that on the GUI. But, if I set a value at design-time from the Object Inspector, it reflects the value as it should be, and the Gauge 
paints the percentage correctly.

Steps to test this behavior:

1. Dragged and dropped the `TGauge` component from the "Samples" palette onto the Form.
2. I set `MaxValue = 100` and `MinValue = 0` in the Object Inspector.
3. I created a textbox (`txtValue`) on the Form.
4. I created a button (`btnSetValueClick`) on the Form and used this code:

   ```
   procedure TMainForm.btnSetValueClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Gauge1.Progress := StrToInt(txtValue.Text);
   end;
   ```

So, I was expecting the Gauge would show the value entered, but it didn't.
When I debug the code, it hits `btnSetValueClick()` and sets the value inside.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** (This is the code in the form.)

```
object Gauge1: TGauge
Left = 53
Top = 81
Width = 191
Height = 113
ParentCustomHint = False
Color = clMenu
ForeColor = clRed
Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
Font.Color = clBlack
Font.Height = -11
Font.Name = 'Default'
Font.Style = []
Kind = gkNeedle
ParentColor = False
ParentFont = False
Progress = 35
```

**EDIT:**

I have created a new project and started from scratch. I put the `TGauge` without changing any single properties of it. And it has started to work although I don't still see the difference can cause this behavior. At least this might give a clue this component can go wrong without an obvious reason, especially to beginners like me.

Please consider the case is as closed. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your steps and it works fine here (tested in delphi 7) Can you view your form as Text and copy / Paste the part for the gauge in your question so we can see all properties for this gauge ?

Comment: For example, If I set the max value to 1000 than setting the progress to 5 will not appear to change anything

Comment: I appreciate your inputs GuidoG. At least that you confirmed, the component works OK.
After your comment, I have created a new project and started from scratch. I put the TGauage without changing any single properties of it. And it has started to work although I don't still see any code differences.

Comment: I tried reproducing with all your property values, it still works at my end. Try deleting the gauge from your form and put a new on on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144821/discussion-between-sener-and-guidog).

Comment: Best to remove the question. Since the behaviour cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @GuidoG, can we continue a bit  in chat?